# node crypto-js AES encrypt -> decrypt usage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

I am trying to generate a simple test of [crypto-js on node](https://github.com/evanvosberg/crypto-js) as follows:

```
'use strict';

var AES = require('crypto-js/aes');
var key = 'passPhrase';
var ecr = function(str)
{
    return AES.encrypt(str, key);
};
var dcr = function(str)
{
    return AES.decrypt(str, key);
};

console.log(dcr(ecr('hello world')));
// expected result is:  hello world
```

The actual result is:

```
{ words: [ 1751477356, 1864398703, 1919706117, 84215045 ],
  sigBytes: 11 }
```

What is the right usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the code to deal any object:

```
'use strict';

var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var key = 'pass phrase';
var ecr = function(obj)
{
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(obj), key);
};
var dcr = function(obj)
{
    return JSON.parse(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(obj, key)
        .toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
};

var s = 'hello world';
console.log(dcr(ecr(s)));

var obj = {
    id: 'ken',
    key: 'password'
};
console.log(dcr(ecr(obj)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh well..
Working Code:

```
'use strict';

var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var key = 'pass phrase';
var ecr = function(str)
{
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(str, key);
};
var dcr = function(str)
{
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(str, key)
        .toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
};

console.log(dcr(ecr('hello world')));
```

Result:

```
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks for input. You are right. I post another answer with a modification.